# Array manipulation in TCL

Tags: tcl

I have the following data each in separate arrays such as atten(), power(), bandwidth(), Time()

```
Atten    Power           Bandwidth      Time

30   1.52E+01   52638515      0

31   1.51E+01   49807360      10

32   1.46E+01   52848230      20

33   1.51E+01   39845888      30
```

I need to change the arrangement to the following format

```
Atten   Power           Bandwidth       Time

30  1.52E+01    52638515       0

30  1.52E+01    49807360      10

31  1.51E+01    52848230      20

31  1.51E+01    39845888      30

. . . .
```

Now i need to make atten() and power() appear twice without changing anything for the arrays bandwidth() and time in an excel in csv format???.. The following is how i write my data to excel in CSV format.

```
 set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]

                    set XlFileFormat(xlCSV) [expr 6]
        set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
                set workbook [$workbooks Add]
        $application DisplayAlerts False
            set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
        set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
        set cells [$worksheet Cells]
                    set rows [array size atten]
        for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {

            $cells Item $row "A" $atten($row)

                                                        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between the formats? They look the same.

Comment: edited the question.. Basically i need to change the arrays atten() power() based on Time().. i need to assign atten(i) to atten(i-1) and power(i) to power(i-1).. but to need to retain the bandwidth() and time()..

Comment: Sounds like your data is really records of records of Atten, Power, Bandwidth for different Times - is that right?  What is the current array structure - what output do you get if you run `parray Atten`, `parray power`, etc. ?

Comment: yes. Atten,power and bandwidth for different times.. I  have atten(),power(), bandwidth(), time() each in seperate arrays.. The source data looks like the first set i mentioned in my question...Please check the question again, i have edited it..

Comment: it is something like for time (0->10) i should have same atten()& power() so here for time 0 and 10, i have the same atten & power such as 30 and 1.52E+01, similarly for time (20->30) i should have same atten() so that would be atten = 31 and power 1.51E+01, and i have to continue this for all data...

Comment: What's still not clear is what are the key values of your arrays.   Are you aware that Tcl arrays can be keyed off any string value?  Are you using integer keys as if they were C arrays?

It sounds like for the Atten and Power columns of your table you want to each value to appear twice, while leaving the other columns unchanged - is that right?

Comment: yes you are right.. It is just i have to make the atten and power columns of the table to appear twice...

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet is example of how to use a chronological list of array keys, in order to print out array contents in order. This is then used to make an array with two of every element.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

proc add_element {array_name key value} {
upvar $array_name aa
if { ![info exists aa($key)] } {
            set aa($key) $value
            lappend aa() $key
        }
}

add_element names 1 Jane
add_element names 2 Tom
add_element names 3 Elisabeth
add_element names 4 Ted
add_element names 5 Sally


 foreach e $names() {
        add_element morenames $e $names($e)
        add_element morenames $[expr $e + 1 ] $names($e)
        }

foreach e $morenames() {
      puts $morenames($e)
}
```

In order to solve your problem you would generate new arrays for atten and power with double element as per the above example. You would then generate your other arrays using a function similar to the example above, unless they already are returned ordered when iterating through them.

You would then iterate through on of the other arrays, say newTime, using something similar to the snippet below:

```
  set rows [array size newTime]
    for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {

        $cells Item $row "A" $newatten($row)
        $cells Item $row "B" $newpower($row)
        $cells Item $row "C" $newbandwidth($row)
        $cells Item $row "C" $newTime($row)
        }
```

The following code snippet is an example of how to remap numeric keys of a TCL Array (Associative array or HashMap).

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set names(1) Jane
set names(2) Tom
set names(3) Elisabeth
set names(4) Robert
set names(5) Julia
set names(6) Victoria

foreach n [array names names] {
 puts $n
 puts $names($n)
}
puts "-------------"

foreach n [array names names] {
    set newnames([expr $n -1]) $names($n)
}

foreach n [array names newnames] {
 puts $n
 puts $newnames($n)
}
```

This isn't sufficient to do what you want.

You would have to do this and then remove `unset` the first element and add `set` a last element.

You haven't specified in your question what your last element would be.

If you are using non numeric keys, e.g string keys then you would have to give those keys some concept of order, whether by mapping them to numeric keys or using some other method.

Note that TCL arrays don't return things in order in a foreach loop unless you tell them to.

TCL lists are better suited to that, as demostrated by.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set i 0
foreach j "a b c" {
puts "$j is item number $i in list x"
incr i
}
```

You also haven't specified what data structures you want to convert to or whether you just want to write the input to screen (using `puts`) or to file.

E.g Whether you would to generate any of the folllowing data structures for your table ?

- A TCL array of TCL arrays (Hashmap of Hashmap)
- A List of Lists
- A TCL array of Lists
- A List of TCL Arrays (List of Hashmap)

For further information see:

- [Arrays Page TCL Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/532)
- [List Page TCL Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/440)
- [Associative Arrays Page TCL Tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl22.html)
- [List Page TCL Tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/tutorial/Tcl14.html)

Comment: actually i need to write these as specified by @Colin Macleod into excel, the following i show i write to excel in CSV format..                                   set XlFileFormat(xlCSV) [expr 6]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Add]
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]                              set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
set cells [$worksheet Cells]                       set rows [array size atten]
         for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
           $cells Item $row "A" $atten($row)}

Comment: It is probably better to add additional information to your question, rather than as a comment to my answer.